# How is this integral trigonometric?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I'm given the following problem:

$\int \frac{3}{\sqrt{1-64x^2}}dx$

As it seems, the solution to this integral is:

$\frac{3}{8}\sin^{-1}{(8x)}$

How does this follow from the trig "rules" of integration? I guess I'm not seeing it. I'm in an accelerated Calc II class, and I want to be sure I *really* get this stuff down.

Comment: Let $8x=\sin(u)$.

Comment: It may help to know that the derivative of $\arcsin(x)$ is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. If you don't know this yet, prove it using the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

Answer (score 5):

Use the substitution $t=8x,\quad\mathrm d t=8\,\mathrm dx$. The  integral becomes
$$\int \frac{3}{\sqrt{1-64x^2}}\,\mathrm dx =\int \frac{3}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\frac{\mathrm dt}8=\frac38\int \frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Ponder

$$(\arcsin(x))'=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, let $x=\frac{\sin(u)}{8}$ then $dx=\frac{1}{8}\cos(u)du$ and substituting gives $$\int \frac{3}{\sqrt{1-64x^2}}dx=\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{3\cos(u)}{\sqrt{1-64(\frac{\sin(u)}{8})^{2}}}du$$
$$=\frac{3}{8}\int \frac{\cos(u)}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(u)}}du=\frac{3}{8}\int1du$$
$$=\frac{3}{8}u+C=\frac{3}{8}\sin^{-1}(8x)+C.$$

Answer (score 0):

Any integral of the form $\sqrt {a^2-x^2}$ follows the substitution $x=a\sin\theta$
so $\sqrt {a^2-x^2}$= $\sqrt {a^2-{a^2\sin^2\theta}}=a\sqrt {1-{\sin^2\theta}} = a\cos\theta$